# rails render action with anchor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, anchor, render, simple-form

i have a form with simple_form gem. if i digit the url in the browser with the anchor tag it works:

```
localhost:3000/contacts/#new_contact #show me the correct form in the page
```

this is my controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @message = Contact.new()
  end

  def create

    @message = Contact.new(msg_params)
    @message.request = request
    if @message.deliver
      redirect_to contacts_path , flash: { success: 'Ok' }
    else
      render action: :index #how can i render the new_contact anchor??
    end

  rescue   ScriptError
    redirect_to contacts_path , flash: { error: 'spam' }
  end

  private
  def msg_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name,:email,:message,:spam)
  end
end
```

this is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message, defaults: { label: false} do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text,input_html: { rows: 7 } %>

    <div class="hidden">
      <%= f.input :spam, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
    </div>

    <%= f.button :submit, 'Send', class: 'btn-block btn-success btn-lg' %>

<% end %>
```

how can i show the new_contact anchor with the render method?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  The reason the link `localhost:3000/contacts/#new_contact` works is because you are routing index to show the form.  This link, `localhost:3000/contacts/#blurp` would also work.  Can you clarify what you are looking for with your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `render` to modify the anchor tag. In fact, `render` has nothing at all to do with the URI.

You can use existing links to link to "/url#anchor", redirect there, or use javascript to achieve the same effect.

You might also need to add `:id => 'anchor'` if the anchor itself isn't setup on the form.

Comment: Is there no way to pass the anchor to render, but i can do it for the redirect_to. e.g. `format.html { redirect_to edit_dashboard_product_path(@product, anchor: 'translations'), notice: 'Product translations were successfully updated.' }` works while `format.html { render :edit, anchor: ''something}` doesn't